# Modifying code to use classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I created a script [here](https://gist.github.com/BrycePearce/07d1fe200418bf2c7f87886fa28d2d16) that extracts some data from a .JSON and creates an object with it. The code works, but I need to add *Source* and *Destination* to a class so I can export it and use it with other files.

So I rewrote my code to store all the data in class [here](https://gist.github.com/BrycePearce/d5238138ef9cde1cd1bbe0ea1702280c). Relevant portions show below:

```
const source = [];
const destination = [];

class Values {
    constructor(source_address, source_lat, source_lng,
        dest_address, dest_lat, dest_lng, scan_type) {
        this.source_address = source_address;
        this.source_lat = source_lat;
        this.source_lng = source_lng;
        this.dest_address = dest_address;
        this.dest_lat = dest_lat;
        this.dest_lng = dest_lng;
        this.scan_type = scan_type;
    }
};
//block is each section of the array
obj.forEach(block => {
    source.push({
        id: Values.source_lat + Values.source_lng,
        "source-lat": Values.source_lat,
        "source-lng": Values.source_lng,
        "source_address": Values.source_address,
        x: {
            valueOf: function () {
                var latlng = [
                    Values.source_lat,
                    Values.source_lng
                ];
                var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
                return xy[0];
            }
        },
        y: {
            valueOf: function () {
                var latlng = [
                    Values.source_lat,
                    Values.source_lng
                ];
                var xy = map.FUNCTION_FOR_CONVERTING_LAT_LNG_TO_X_Y(latlng);
                return xy[1];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But it returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "x": {},
    "y": {}
  }
]
```

Why are all the data values reading as null? How should I approach fixing this problem?

Comment: You are attempting to access properties like they are static (`Values.foo`), but they are setup as instance properties and require `new Values(...)`

Comment: Code relevant to understanding the question and offering a solution MUST be pasted into your question and appropriately formatted.  It is the policy of this site that relevant information cannot only be available via external links.  For starters, those external links tend to change or disappear over time rendering this question worthless as a repository of interesting question/answers which is part of what stackoverflow is about.

Comment: @RobM. Thanks for the response. I'm having trouble getting that to work, do you happen to have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even initialising `Values`? How would you expect it to return anything?

Before you do your loops you need to initialise it with some data, like so:

```
var valueClass = new Value(--your constructor values here--);
```

Doing this you'll be able to access your class values, e.g `valueClass.dest_address`.

An example with a small snippet of your code:

```
var valueClass = new Value(--your constructor values here--);

//block is each section of the array
obj.forEach(block => {
    source.push({
        id: valueClass.source_lat + valueClass.source_lng,
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to initialize values. However, this still returns a null values: var valueClass = new Values(source_address, source_lat, source_lng,
        dest_address, dest_lat, dest_lng, scan_type);            ...Even if I precede the variable names with this.